# How to change background color of ion-radio without updating background color of entire app?

Tags: css, ionic-framework, ionic4, ion-radio-group

I am trying to change the background of the `ion-radio-group` below to match the other rows:

[image]

I have shown my HTML & CSS below.

I tried adding the `rowStyle` class to the row. That changes the background of the row, but the radio button's are still appearing blue.

If I update the `--ion-background-color` value in my CSS for `ion-content`, the radio button background does change, but so does the entire page.

I just want all the rows to match.

Can someone please tell me how to do this?

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid style="width: 75%">

    <ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="userType">
      <ion-row class="rowStyle">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Customer</ion-label>
          <ion-radio value="customer"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Supplier</ion-label>
          <ion-radio value="supplier"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-radio-group>

    <ion-row class="rowStyle">
      <ion-icon name="person" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row class="rowStyle">
      <ion-icon name="mail" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
      <ion-input type="email" placeholder="Your Email" [(ngModel)]="email"></ion-input>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row class="rowStyle">
      <ion-icon name="key" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
      <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Your Password" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-button expand="block" shape="round" fill="outline" color="light" style="margin-top: 20px;" (click)="signUp()">Sign Up</ion-button>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>



ion-content {
    --ion-background-color:#3dc2ff;
  }

  .logo { 
    font-size: 25vh;
    margin-top: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }

  h1, h6 {
    color: white;
    font-size: 1em;
    background-color: danger
  }

  .rowStyle {
    background-color: white;
    padding-left: 10px;
    border-radius: 30px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

    ion-icon {
      margin-top: 13px;
      margin-right: 10px;
    }
  }
```

I added the `rowStyle`class to the row. The background of the tag is appearing white, but the background of the 2 radio buttons isn't changing.

Here is what it looks like when I tried to apply the 1st answer:

[image]

Comment: I guess you're close to fix the issue, send the css you used for those buttons.

Answer (score 0):

You can handle it in 2 ways as mentioned below:

1. Create a selector class and add the `color`.
   OR
2. You should use the `ion-item` to get value to be changed:

```css
ion-content {
  --ion-background-color: #3dc2ff;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 25vh;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h1,
h6 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: danger
}

.rowStyle {
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

ion-item {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid style="width: 75%">

    <ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="userType">
      <ion-row class="rowStyle">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Customer</ion-label>
          <ion-radio value="customer"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label>Supplier</ion-label>
          <ion-radio value="supplier"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-radio-group>

    <ion-row class="rowStyle">
      <ion-icon name="person" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row class="rowStyle">
      <ion-icon name="mail" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
      <ion-input type="email" placeholder="Your Email" [(ngModel)]="email"></ion-input>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row class="rowStyle">
      <ion-icon name="key" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
      <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Your Password" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-button expand="block" shape="round" fill="outline" color="light" style="margin-top: 20px;" (click)="signUp()">Sign Up</ion-button>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

**OR**

using `selector` class:

```css
ion-content {
  --ion-background-color: #3dc2ff;
}

.logo {
  font-size: 25vh;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

h1,
h6 {
  color: white;
  font-size: 1em;
  background-color: danger
}

.rowStyle {
  background-color: white;
  padding-left: 10px;
  border-radius: 30px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.radioBtn {
  padding: 5px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<ion-content>
  <ion-grid style="width: 75%">

    <ion-radio-group [(ngModel)]="userType">
      <ion-row class="rowStyle">
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label class="radioBtn">Customer</ion-label>
          <ion-radio value="customer"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
        <ion-item>
          <ion-label class="radioBtn">Supplier</ion-label>
          <ion-radio value="supplier"></ion-radio>
        </ion-item>
      </ion-row>
    </ion-radio-group>

    <ion-row class="rowStyle">
      <ion-icon name="person" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
      <ion-input type="text" placeholder="Your Name" [(ngModel)]="name"></ion-input>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row class="rowStyle">
      <ion-icon name="mail" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
      <ion-input type="email" placeholder="Your Email" [(ngModel)]="email"></ion-input>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-row class="rowStyle">
      <ion-icon name="key" color="secondary"></ion-icon>
      <ion-input type="password" placeholder="Your Password" [(ngModel)]="password"></ion-input>
    </ion-row>

    <ion-button expand="block" shape="round" fill="outline" color="light" style="margin-top: 20px;" (click)="signUp()">Sign Up</ion-button>
  </ion-grid>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. But I tried your first solution, & that isn't working. I've attached an image above to show how it is displaying with my code